# Validation for comment forms

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I am working on a comment system in Codeigniter and would appreciate some advice on what kind of validation rules that I should employ. I don't want to allow any images or other any HTML.

So far I just have `trim` and `max_length` set. I also run the content through `htmlspecialchars` before I insert in the database. I have XSS filtering enabled globally.

What other precautions should I take? Is htmlspecialchars enough for preventing Javascript or other malicious code from being entered?

Comment: You should *not* be running it through `htmlspecialchars` before putting it in the database. When escaping, you should do it at the last possible moment, so that the data is usable for other purposes. In this case, you should be `htmlspecialchars`ing when you output it to the page.

Comment: If you don't want HTML at all, use `strip_tags` on the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably do a regular [form validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) on required and max_length, and obviously xss filtering before pushing things to the database. The htmlspecialchars should only be applied to characters that aren't in tags, so you can't just do htmlspecialchars directly. You need to:

1 - strip the tag elements (and store them) like "`<br/>`" or "`<b>`", but not their content, that means nothing inside the "`<b>`" and "`</b>`". You can probably do this with a [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

2 - execute htmlentities on all the remaining text

3 - remove all unwanted explicit tags (from the stored bunch of tags)

```
strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

4 - then filter the allowed tags for attributes and content. It's not uncommon for hackers to use code like

```
<b onMouseOver="window.open(..)"></b>
```

To fix this, either you'll have to do a little bit of extra work and probably work with some regex-es. If you want me to write some more sample code let me know.

6 - re-add the tag elements back to the document.

I just basically cooked this up right now. The algorithm can be improved in efficiency (i.e. strip the unwanted tags first, and then proceed with filtering html entities and tag contents) but I'll leave that up to you.

This is as far as I can see the potential hacks right now. There might be other ways to hack your input though, so you might want to check what other comment box systems out there use for their validation, such as the [phpbb forum system](http://www.phpbb.com/). Another option might be to use the phpbb square-bracket format to deal with tags so you don't let users input ANY html tags whatsoever, but instead use square-bracket tags that you control.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: yes, this is a very good answer. I've been looking into HTMLPurifier and I think it will help with properly dealing with tags.